# Mysql - unknown column in ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a little problem with a simple query. Here it is:

```
SELECT `T_COURS`.`COU_DATE`,
`T_SESSIONS`.*,
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE`,     `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_CATEGORIE`,
`T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_DESCRIPTION`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_MIN_PART`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_MAX_PART`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_PRIX`, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_LANGUE`
FROM `T_FORMATIONS`
INNER JOIN `T_COURS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID`
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` ON `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID`
WHERE `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ETAT` = 1
ORDER BY `T_COURS`.`COU_DATE` ASC, `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_TITRE` ASC, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE` ASC LIMIT 5
```

When I try to run it, I get this message :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'T_SESSIONS.SES_ID' in 'on clause'
```

I don't really understand why because everything exists in my database?

I looked for answers on the Internet but it didn't help me (or maybe I didn't understand the answers I read).

Comment: Post the database schemes as well, please.

Comment: I think you have your two joins swapped. `T_SESSIONS` doesn't exist at the time it is parsing the `T_COURS` line.

Comment: put "INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` ON `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID`" before "INNER JOIN `T_COURS` ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID`"

Comment: You are aware that those ugly backticks aren't really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your full table structure, I would start by swapping your `JOIN` order, you are joining `T_SESSIONS` after you are trying to use it in your current version.  You currently have:

```
FROM `T_FORMATIONS`
INNER JOIN `T_COURS` 
  ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID`
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` 
  ON `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID`
```

change it to:

```
FROM `T_FORMATIONS`
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` 
  ON `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID`
INNER JOIN `T_COURS` 
  ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID`
```

Making your full query:

```
SELECT `T_COURS`.`COU_DATE`,
  `T_SESSIONS`.*,
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE`,     
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_CATEGORIE`,
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_DESCRIPTION`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_MIN_PART`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_MAX_PART`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_PRIX`, 
  `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_LANGUE`
FROM `T_FORMATIONS`
INNER JOIN `T_SESSIONS` 
  ON `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_ID` = `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_FOR_ID`
INNER JOIN `T_COURS` 
  ON `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ID` = `T_COURS`.`COU_SES_ID`
WHERE `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_ETAT` = 1
ORDER BY `T_COURS`.`COU_DATE` ASC, `T_SESSIONS`.`SES_TITRE` ASC, `T_FORMATIONS`.`FOR_TITRE` ASC 
LIMIT 5
```